# Does a ajax callback function guarantee synchronous execution?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

For example:

```
ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
      ...
      ...
      success: function(response) {
        event2();
      }
    });
}
```

If we have a call like:

```
event1();
ajaxCall();
event3();
```

Would it be always guaranteed that the order of execution of events be
event1() then event2() and event3() without setting the async flag ?

Comment: Never set `async:false`, and no, the order would not be guaranteed, nor should you rely on any such order, the ajax calls are done when they are done. However what you seem to be asking is if the functions will be executed in that order, and they will, they might just not complete in that order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX is **Asynchronous** JAX :) There's your answer.

If you want to make a synchronous call, you need to set the `async: false` flag. But then the `success` callback won't be called at all and you would need to put the `event2();` line just below the `$.ajax` call.

Also see [Mike C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855414/does-a-ajax-callback-function-guarantee-synchronous-execution/35855428#answer-35855464). The synchronous calls are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you're right if you set `async` to `false`. However, [synchronous AJAX has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) and jQuery [officially dropped support for it after v1.8](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

So I would suggest you avoid trying to use synchronous AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The callback function will fire when the event that triggers it (i.e. the HTTP response) happens.

A function you call *immediately* after you **assign** the callback will still be called *immediately*.

The order of execution will still be:

```
event1();
ajaxCall();
    $.ajax();
event3();
success();
    event2();
```